# Reach bottom of listview, android?

Tags: android, listview

I have listview in which data is being added dynamically.
When a click of the button, it goes to another activity and listview appears.
I want it to show the last elements of the listview on the click of the button?
How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scroll to bottom of listview by doing following:

```
listView.setSelection(listAdapter.getCount() - 1);
```